# @id/ has errors in android layout

Tags: android, layout

This is probably something I have overlooked and is simple but I can not figure out why I get an error at every @/id line on each of the following text views. there are errors at @id/buttons_layout, dice_4, dice_6, ect.

```
android:id="@id/buttons_layout"
android:layout_width="330.0dip"
android:layout_height="450.0dip"
android:layout_gravity="top|center"
android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dip"
android:gravity="center"
android:stretchColumns="0,1"
android:visibility="visible" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/dice_4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/dice_4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/dice_6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/dice_6" />
 </TableRow>

 <TableRow
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/dice_10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/dice_10" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/dice_20"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/dice_20" />
 </TableRow>

 <TableRow
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/planeswalker_dice"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/planeswalker_dice" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/coin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/quarter_head" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `android:id="@id/dice_4"` to `android:id="@+id/dice_4"`. You want to create new IDs

Comment: I dont know how I overlooked that both in writing it and again posting it here...Thank you very much.